# Centering footer relative to paper in memoir

Tags: horizontal-alignment, header-footer, memoir

I would like to center the footer of a pagestyle not relative to the margins of the page, but rather relative to the width of the physical paper. I created a pagestyle specifically for the title page. I thought that the `\makerunningwidth` line would properly compute the center of the page, but, as you can plainly see, the page number is not aligned with the rest of the text (which is absolutely aligned relative to the center of the paper).

The document is generated with

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\copypagestyle{INRSDocExamTitle}{plain}
\makerunningwidth{INRSDocExamTitle}{\paperwidth}
\makeoddfoot{INRSDocExamTitle}{}{\thepage}{}
\makeevenfoot{INRSDocExamTitle}{}{\thepage}{}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{INRSDocExamTitle}
\newlength{\centeradjust}
\calccentering{\centeradjust}  % Calculate center length and stores in centeradjust
\begin{adjustwidth*}{\centeradjust}{-\centeradjust}   % Adjust center
\begin{adjustwidth}{-1cm}{-1cm}  
  \begin{center}
  \begin{OnehalfSpace}
    \vspace*{3\baselineskip}
     {\Large Centered text using adjustwidth (as per the \texttt{memoir} manual)}

     \vfill

    {\large This foooter is not centered with respect to the page,\\
    but with respect to the type block. \\
    $\downarrow$
    }
   \vspace*{3\baselineskip}
 \end{OnehalfSpace}
 \end{center}
\end{adjustwidth}
\end{adjustwidth*}

\end{document}
```

Is there a way to center the footer relative to the page, not the  margins?

[image: Sample PDF]

Comment: Is this for every page or just the title page?

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Only the title page.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Done.

Comment: Why do you even have a page number on the title page? Most people don't

Comment: @daleif Not my choice. It's my university.

Comment: And how are the university advising users to get this layout in other systems?

Comment: If you are only centering the title page, there are much simpler solutions, the most obvious of which is to use the geometry package \newgeometry and \restoregeometry to create even margins.

Comment: @daleif It's the template for a doctoral exam. They number the title page. It's stupid, but there's nothing I can do about it. They're pretty stiff with their conventions.

Comment: @JohnKormylo That is indeed a great idea. And it's robust, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to offset the page number to compensate for the uneven margins.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\copypagestyle{INRSDocExamTitle}{plain}
\makeoddfoot{INRSDocExamTitle}{}{\thepage\offset}{}
\makeevenfoot{INRSDocExamTitle{}{\thepage\offset}{}
\newcommand{\offset}% center page number in text area
{\ifodd\value{page}\hspace{\dimexpr 2in+2\oddsidemargin+\textwidth-\paperwidth}%
\else\hspace{\dimexpr 2in+2\evensidemargin+\textwidth-\paperwidth}%
\fi}

\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}% used only to show center of page

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{INRSDocExamTitle}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[red] (current page.north) -- (current page.south);
\end{tikzpicture}

odd page
\newpage
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[red] (current page.north) -- (current page.south);
\end{tikzpicture}

even page
\end{document}
```

Comment: The documentclass is `memoir`, not `book`

Comment: This seems to work. Care to explain in a bit more detail the offset command?

Comment: The left margin is 1in + \oddsidemargin on odd pages and 1in + \evensidemargin on even pages. The rignt margin is \paperwidth - \textwidth - the left margin. The left margin - the right margin is what is used in the \hspace.

Comment: Ok. Is the `1in` constant, or can it change if, for instance, I use other packages?

Comment: It's a legacy from plain TeX and will never change.

Answer (score 1):

IMO the easiest thing to do is to manually code this particular pagestyle:

```
\makeatletter
\@namedef{ps@INRSDocExamTitle}{%
  \@namedef{@oddfoot}{%
    \hspace{-\spinemargin}%
      \parbox[b]{\paperwidth}{%
        \strut\hfill \thepage \hfill\strut%
        }%
    }%
}
\makeatother
```

Just to show the effect

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}

\setlrmarginsandblock{1cm}{4cm}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout

\makeatletter
\@namedef{ps@INRSDocExamTitle}{%
  \@namedef{@oddfoot}{%
    \hspace{-\spinemargin}%
      \parbox[b]{\paperwidth}{%
        \strut\hfill \thepage \hfill\strut%
        }%
    }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}


\thispagestyle{INRSDocExamTitle}

\newlength{\centeradjust}
\calccentering{\centeradjust}  % Calculate center length and stores in centeradjust
\begin{adjustwidth*}{\centeradjust}{-\centeradjust}   % Adjust center
\begin{adjustwidth}{-1cm}{-1cm}  
  \begin{center}
  \begin{OnehalfSpace}
    \vspace*{3\baselineskip}
     {\Large Centered text using adjustwidth (as per the \texttt{memoir} manual)}

     \vfill

     This foooter is not centered with respect to the page,\\
    but with respect to the type block. 

    $\downarrow$

   \noindent
   test\hfill\smash{%
      \rule[-3.7cm]{0.4pt}{4cm}%
    }\hfill test%



   \vspace*{3\baselineskip}
 \end{OnehalfSpace}
 \end{center}
\end{adjustwidth}
\end{adjustwidth*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is also a great answer, but I'm not sure what `\hb@xt@` does. Care to explain it?

Comment: Look in the kernel sources (source2e.pdf), short for `\hbox to`. I'm quite sure we could make do with just the `\parbox`

Comment: Just tested, the `\hb@ct@` is not needed, I'll remove it from the example.